# How to run two queries i) from: ii) keyword using Postman's Twitter API?

Tags: api, search, twitter, postman, tweets

I am new to Postman and have successfully got started using the Twitter API v2 collection. I'm able to run a single query 'from:ukhomeoffice' and separately run a query using a keyword but when I try to run both i.e. selecting x2 queries the response = "message": "Duplicate parameters are not allowed: the `query` query parameter"

What I'm looking to do is search for tweets from a particular user (in my case the UK home office) also containing a keyword. Is there a way to do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: what are you passing in to the query parameter? Are you adding multiple query parameters? You only need a single query, but you can have multiple terms as part of that.

Comment: Thanks @AndyPiper. I've been told Postman will not allow multiple queries. I am needing to search the archive for x1 key word but also need to filter from one particular account. Any ideas how I can do both of these simultaneously with Postman?

Comment: so the value of the single `query` parameter should contain `from:ukhomeoffice keyword`